# How can I trick a program into thinking a network path is local?

Tags: windows-10

The title pretty much says it all. I would like to have a program believe that a network path, e.g. `\\myserver\myfolder\` is actually something like `C:\anotherfolder`. I already tried soft linking but the program can detect it is indeed a network path.

Comment: Have you tried: `mklink /d "c:\data\folder" "\\server\shareddata\"`

Comment: @harrymc Yes, as I said I already tried soft linking.

Comment: Did you try to make it two-step, like mapping the network share to drive `Z:`, then doing the `mklink /D "c:\data\folder" Z:` ?

Comment: Have a look at creating a shim for the application using the Microsoft Application Compatability Toolkit.  The one you want to set is the `CorrectFilePaths` I believe to redirect one path to another.  Should work. Searching for `CorrectFilePaths` will probably throw something up you can use as a guide.

Comment: @harrymc Tried the double soft link approach, still didn't work. The program is asking for path properties and effectively determining it's a network path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I managed to trick the installer by a much simpler method that doesn't involve too much black magic. I created a virtual drive which is, basically, a mapping from a file in my remote folder via the Disk Management section.

Detailed steps can be found in: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-and-set-vhdx-or-vhd-windows-10

Answer (score 0):

I assume I checked with sufficient technical expertise that all those very good reasons which deny this kind of setup do not apply to your use case ([this article](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2000/08/22/three-wrong-ideas-from-computer-science/) will give you a few ideas about that - see section 3).

As far as I know, there are no workarounds to spoof this through onboard windows tools (well depending on the software using to access the files). But there is third party software like [Dokan](https://dokan-dev.github.io/) which should allow you to achieve it. At least it worked in all of my cases but if your software is checking for this specifically, of course, it will detect it.

Another possibility would be to fiddle around with symlinks a little further, but I assume you tried all options. Otherwise, it might be wise to look into [this guide](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/).